# PHP:Calculating time difference between server and client

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

I am building a chat for my website and I want to calculate the time difference between the server and the client. I am using the following code to get the time difference and put it in a hidden input field. But it doesn't work.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
var time = new Date().getTime()/1000;
$.post('timediff.php',{time:time},function(response){
    alert(response);
});
</script>
```

And in my timediff.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['time'])){
    $client_time = $_POST['time'];
    $server_time = time();
    $time_diff = $server_time - $client_time;
    echo $time_diff;
}
?>
```

I tested this on another computer which has the same time setting as the server but the result that I am getting is larger. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any better way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accounting for the latency between the client and the server?  Even if they are one and the same, if it takes > 1 ms to process the response, you will get a non-zero difference.

**EDIT:**  Try `getTimezoneOffset()` (JavaScript, returns minutes) and `DateTime::getOffset()` (PHP, returns seconds).  It's possible `getTime()` and `time()` are returning time-zone-dependent values.  If you haven't set the timezone in your PHP script, that could also be a factor.

You might also try this in your PHP:

```
echo $client_time."\n".$server_time;
```

It could be useful to see what time JS and PHP are each reporting; it may be very different from the system time for any number of reasons.

Comment: they are two different computers.. and both have the same time setting but the result I am getting is like 40,000 seconds..

Comment: Any chance it's roughly 43,200 seconds?  That would be exactly half a day, and that's what you expect if one thinks it's, say 12:51 A.M. and one thinks it's 12:51 P.M.

Comment: is there any other way to do this?